# How to call private & public functions inside namespace

Tags: javascript

I have a namespace that has few private and public functions. How do I call them from another public function (within same namespace)?

```
var myns = (function () {    
  var module = {};   

  function private_F1() {        
  }

  function private_F2() {

  }    

  // public
  module.public_doSomething = function () {        
  };

  module.Init= function () {
    // Why cant i call functions inside the same namespace using "this"

    this.private_F1(); //does not work with "this" keyword

    private_F1(); //worked  without "this" keyword

    this.public_doSomething() //does not work with "this" keyword

    public_doSomething //does not work without "this" keyword

    myns.public_doSomething() //worked with namespace
  };

  return module;

})();
```

Comment: `this` refers to an instance of the object. your *private* functions aren't part of that object, thus, it wouldn't make sense for them to be accessible with `this.`

Comment: To expand on my earlier comment, your *public* functions aren't part of `this` either. They are defined to be part of the `module` object. You could reference them as `module.public_doSomething()` as well. You can reference them from `myns` because you return `module` and set `myns` to it.

Comment: should look into the `module pattern` `IIFE`

Comment: A function's *this* is an object (except in strict mode where it can be any type), you can access members of that object such as *myns.public_doSomething*. However, *module* is a variable so is resolved on the scope chain, not via object properties of *this*.

Comment: thank you all. it was confusing for me as i'm C# developer. In C#  using "this" keyword i can call any instance method with-in "this" instance.